# I gave money to dad - do I need an article here?

Tags: articles

Do I need an article in the phrases:

"I gave money to a/the dad".

"When a/the son was conscripted to the military, I became concerned for his life."

etc.

Answer (score 5):

"Dad" is quite a personal word, you use it when referring to your own father or the father of someone you know. Although it's grammatically correct to say "the dad", it sounds a bit strange using a personal word without referring to an actual person. You would either say "his dad", or "the father":

> "I gave money to the father"
>
> "I gave money to my dad"

You don't *need* an article for "dad", since it's also a proper noun. But the only time you would use it is when you're talking to someone inside your immediate family:

> "I gave the money to Dad"

The same applies to the word "son", except unlike dad/father we don't have an impersonal word for "son". The reason it sounds strange to say "a son" is because the word implies a relationship with someone, so you need to introduce them in the sentence:

> "When her son joined the military, I became concerned for his life."
>
> "John has three children; when the son joined the military, I became concerned for his life."

---

Note: You **wouldn't** say:

> "I gave the money to Son"

If you're the father talking about your son to a family member, you call them by their first name. The only time "son" is a proper noun is when you're *talking to* your son:

> "I gave the money to you, Son"
>
> "I gave the money to my son"

Comment: Why do u capitalize the "Dad"?

Comment: @Anixx - when it's capitalized, it's used as a proper noun, and hence does not take an article. P.S. A nice point, Mark, which I missed!

Comment: Proper noun??? Can u please give some references where "dad" is used with capitalization?

Comment: How do u define then "proper noun"? Why u do not capitalize the word "son" when u claim u use it as "proper noun"?

Comment: @Anixx "Why u do not capitalize the word "son" when u claim u use it as proper noun?" Well caught, I've edited the post

Comment: @Anixx A proper noun is just a fancy way of saying it's someone's name.

Comment: I think when u are talking to your son, you are using address, so one does not need article (like in calling the policeman "policeman!, officer!" without an article. So please prove that "I gave the money to you, Son" is a proper noun rather than address. Or when calling a policeman, you also is using a proper noun?

Comment: @Mark so if "son" of "dad" is not someone's name, how can it be a proper noun?

Comment: @Anixx Calling someone "policeman" or "officer" is like calling them "sir". You don't know their name so you're using their job title instead. If I knew the policeman's name, let's say it was John Smith, I would call them "Officer Smith". Note that the word "Officer" is capitalized because it's part of the proper noun.

Comment: Or you could just read [When should “Mom” and “Dad” be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44846/when-should-mom-and-dad-be-capitalized?rq=1) and [Capitalization of “sister” and “brother”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172615/capitalization-of-sister-and-brother?rq=1) and [Do I capitalize s on “son” when it's used casually such as “Say hi to your pa for me, son.”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147181/do-i-capitalize-s-on-son-when-its-used-casually-such-as-say-hi-to-your-pa-fo/147240#147240).